# Regular Expression - How to validate price field if I enter below 30?

Tags: validation, pattern-matching, expression

I have used `pattern` I want to price equal 30 or Greater BUT not less.

Look my html code -

```
<input type="text" required="required" pattern="29+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$" data-error="#Please enter price equal 30 or more" placeholder="Price" id="price" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="price" />
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
```

Above co I have used `pattern="29+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$"` but this pattern not working. I have tried in different expression like `29*\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$`, `^\d{30,}$`, `^[0-9]\{30,}\$` these expressions also not working.

I am using bootstrap validator. Link = http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-examples

Please help me.

***Edit : ***

Now I am using `^[3-9]+\d*$` this is working fine. But it takes `3` or more than `3`. I need `30` or more

Comment: This has been said and written so many times: do *not* use regex for such purpose!!!

Comment: I am using now this `^[3-9]+\d*$` this is working fine. But It takes `3` or more than `3`. I need `30` or more

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be using regexes for this kind of task. But if you *do* want to, try this:

```
([3-9][0-9]|[0-9]{3,})
```